# How to escape special SQL characters in regular expression in Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a text field to accept regular expressions from the UI. For these regular expressions, I have a search capability and want to do a search. I am using prepared statements and the DB is mysql. When I do a search on '%', I only want search regex starting with '%'. But, since '%' is wildcard in mysql, I get all the regex in the search. How to escape it.

Comment: I want to even escape the other mysql wildcards like '_'.

Comment: are you talking about regular expressions or the LIKE operator? Because % is NOT a special character in regular expressions. Please edit your question to be more clear. And/or, write the SQL condition you want to use as an example.

Comment: I am storing the regular expressions in the DB. And I am using LIKE operator in SQL to search the regular expression. Sample sql : "Select expression from REGEX where expression LIKE '%';". I want to use % in the sql as normal character.

Comment: OK, I posted solution for PHP as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use a backslash before the character, as shown in the [MySQL documentation section 9.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences):

```
\0  An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.  
\'  A single quote ("'") character.  
\"  A double quote (""") character.  
\b  A backspace character.  
\n  A newline (linefeed) character.  
\r  A carriage return character.  
\t  A tab character.  
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control+Z). See note following the table.  
\\  A backslash ("\") character.  
\%  A "%" character. See note following the table.  
\_  A "_" character. See note following the table.
```

Note (from the MySQL documentation):

> If you use "\%" or "\_" outside of pattern-matching contexts, they evaluate to the strings "\%" and "\_", not to "%" and "_".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, you may escape %, _ and characters using this code:

```
$escaped = addcslashes($str, "%_");
```

The \ (backslash) and quotes you of course must also escape (as always! To prevent SQL injection), e.g. by `mysql_real_escape_string()`.