# How to escape parentheses in a REGEXP clause

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In my database I have some keys like this:

```
custom_field_languages(0)language
custom_field_languages(1)language
custom_field_languages(2)language
...
```

And I need all of them. But this doesn't work:

```
REGEXP '^custom_field_languages([0-9])language'
```

This also doesn't work.

```
REGEXP '^custom_field_languages\([0-9]\)language'
```

This works but isn't 100% accurate.

```
REGEXP '^custom_field_languages.[0-9].language'
```

What is the correct way to escape normal parentheses?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010372/how-to-escape-special-sql-characters-in-regular-expression-in-mysql) relevant? I would've thought that the backslashes would work. Are you running this query directly in MySQL or through a scripting language that might consume those backslashes?

Comment: I'm running this in PHP.

Comment: If this is inside double quotes you'll need to double up on backslashes or else you're just telling PHP you want a literal bracket. `"\("` is simply `"("` whereas `"\\("` is actually `\(` once it gets to MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape parentheses with square brackets, like this:

```
REGEXP '^custom_field_languages[(][0-9][)]language'
```

This is especially useful when you need to embed your query string into a language that provides its own interpretation for backslashes inside string literals.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bd92/3)

Comment: This is a very creative solution - not normally how I think of using character classes but that's a great idea